# Angularjs Material Design project Layout issue

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

Using Angularjs Material framework, I aligned the content (containing cards) to the center, the problem is when I increase the height of one card, the height of the adjacent card also increases. Example code http://embed.plnkr.co/eaLjJDbjL1KnOI4jLYyO/preview

The cards will have dynamic height, and should align one after another both horizontally as well as vertically.

I am trying to achieve some thing like this:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6ocJpsXmVLU/VTgSj9wd_CI/AAAAAAAAACs/PavEWs9wiGM/s1600/cardLayout.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with Angular.  It looks like your example is using flexbox CSS, which is the cause of your columns having equal height.  Remove all the flex attributes and your cards will take take the height of the contained content.  If you are looking for a masonry tile layout you'll likely need JavaScript to help with that since elements float left and clear one another.  Take a look at this and see if this helps http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Would the angular-material [grid-list](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.gridList) work in a similar way?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Angular Material Design project, but I think the grid list might work for what you're wanting to do.  You may want to update your title of this thread to attract folks who have worked with the Material Design framework.